# Automatically refresh div id every 15 seconds with code snippet from .php file

Tags: ajax

I want to automatically load **song-history.php** into the div id **#song-history** every 15 seconds via ajax without refreshing the actual template page in my child theme.

**song-history.php** is just a php file with a small code snippet fetching song history data via an api on a subdomain streaming music. This works as expected upon page load but I can not for the life of me get it to automatically refresh via ajax though, keeping the song history up to date as new songs are played. I've tried every google snippet possible.

Why won't this example, or any of the others I've tried work for me in WordPress? It seems really straightforward.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadlink(){
    $('#song-history').load('song-history.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Where is your song-history.php file located?

Comment: root child theme directory.

**/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/child/songhistory.php** or **https://example.com/wp-content/themes/child/song-history.php**

Comment: You better rewrite your code and use WP-AJAX for that. When you create a new file in your theme's folder, WordPress does not generate a page for it automatically.

Comment: song-history.php is called within my child template on page-home-custom.php (custom home page). the song history shows fine on my site when you visit the page, but automatically refreshing the song history with that code doesn't.